# Azure Data Flows

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to regularly update an existing set of 30+ CSV files with new data (append to the end). There is also a requirement to possibly remove the first X rows as Y rows are added to the end.

Am I using the correct services for this and in the correct manner?

- Azure Blob Storage to store the Existing and Update files.
- Azure DataFactory with DataFlows. A PipeLine and DataFlow per CSV I want to transform that conducts a merge of datasets (existing + update), producing a
  sink fileset that drops the new combined CSV back into Blob
  storage.
- A trigger on the Blob Storage Updates directory to trigger the pipeline when a new update file is uploaded.

Questions:

- Is this the best approach for this problem, I need a solution with minimal input from users (I'll take care of Azure ops so long as all they have to do is upload a file and download the new one)
- Do I need a pipeline and dataflow per CSV file? Or could I have one per transformation type (ie one for just appending, another for appending and removing first X rows)
- I was going to create a directory in blob storage for each of the CSVs (30+ Dirs) and create a dataset for each directories existing and update files.
- Then create a dataset for each output file into some new/ directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of your CSVs, you can either perform the append right inside of the data flow by taking both the new data as well as the existing CSV file as a source and then Union the 2 files together to make a new file.

Or, with larger files, use the Copy Activity "merge files" setting to merge the 2 files together.